# rails service management in development? ( foreman does not start all services )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, service, ruby-on-rails-3.2, god, foreman

My foreman gem does not load all my services.
This is my Procfile:

```
search: redis-server
search: bundle exec rake resque:start  &&> log/resque_worker_queue.log
search: bundle exec rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production & &> log/private_pub.log
search: bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run
```

Is it possible to fix this Or should I better use GOD gem even in development mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process types must all have unique names. It appears from your `Procfile` that you've named all the processes `search`. Try the following as your Procfile:

```
redis:  redis-server
worker: bundle exec rake resque:start  &&> log/resque_worker_queue.log
web:    bundle exec rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production & &> log/private_pub.log
solr:   bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run
```

Comment: Ok tried this in the end I still have issues with services not working so not sure this really is a 100% solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify more details on which services are not loaded and what the error / console output is.

The issue is most likely that you are starting the processes in the background (with the `&` option), and foreman does not support this (see [this wiki page](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/wiki/Process-immediately-terminating). Additionally, it is better (for development at least) to not redirect the output to log files - foreman handles the log output for you in a nice way.

I also believe you need to use `resque:work` instead of `resque:start`.

You can try this:

```
redis:  redis-server
worker: QUEUE=* bundle exec rake resque:work
web:    bundle exec rackup private_pub.ru -s thin -E production
solr:   bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run
```

If any of these are still not working, check that the commands work if you use them directly in the console, and that they stay in the foreground.